# Regex to find all direct links to images

Tags: regex

I'm trying to make a regex that finds all direct links to images, for example:

`http://example.com/image.jpg` or `images/image.png` (relative url).

But not `http://google.com/searchbyimage?image_url=http://example.com/image.jpg` or `http://example.com/http://example.com/image.png`.

So basically it should end with `.jpg` or `.png` and it can have `http://` or `https://` at the beginning, but not anywhere else.

Can someone help me with this?

Thanks!

Comment: Using/creating a regex to parse a URL is already well covered on this site.  If you have access to an app language like Java or C# then there are APIs which can very accurately probe a URL to answer your question.

Comment: That second non-match looks funny. Also, it isn't clear, do all links have `http` or `https` in them: Is that a requirement? Is the relative URL only `/images/`?

Comment: There are definitely real links that look like the second non-match. Like I said it can begin with `http://` or `https://`, but it doesn't have to. It just can't have them in the middle.

Comment: [`^https?://(?:[^/]+/)+[^/]+\.(?:jpe?g|png|gif|tiff?|bmp)(?:\?.*)?(?:#.*)?$`](https://regex101.com/r/ri4Nus/1)?

Comment: ctwheels's regex seems ok for absolute URLs. To catch relative URLs as well,it needs a few modifications:

`^(?:(?:https?:/)?/)?(?:[^/]+/)+[^/]+\.(?:jpe?g|png|gif|tiff?|bmp)(?:\?.*)?(?:#.*)?$`


https://regex101.com/r/WdKAsl/1